# Spring prevent automatic id for form tags

Tags: java, spring, jquery-ui, jsp

I am using spring form tags for forms in my webapp. Now I am seeing spring autogenerate ids for all input, select elements.
I have several forms in separate tabs which may have inputs with the same name (eg. user_category in ). Spring uses the name of the input element as the id for the tag. This becomes a problem as I have several inputs with the same names in separate forms of the same page. I end up with multiple select elements having the same id. The problem becomes worse when I use the [jquery-ui-multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) plugin to decorate my select box. If there are multiple selectors on the same page with the same id then changing selection on one of the selectors affects another.

One workaround I have found is to give all my select boxes unique IDs explicitly. But I think a cleaner way would be to prevent spring from generating id on the form tags altogether. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring `<form:...>` tags allow you to specify an `id` attribute, e.g.:

```
<form:select id="select1"...>
```

So, you can specify your own `id`s.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah thats the workaround I mentioned "give all my select boxes unique IDs explicitly". I wanted to disable the automatic ID in spring without giving 10 unique ids specifically. Any way we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that there only one simple and obvious way to prevent writing of "id"-attribute (at least in Spring 4.1.4)  - is just to set an empty id:

```
<form:input id="" .../>
```

then *AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag#resolveId()* will return null and *AbstractFormTag#writeOptionalAttribute* will skip it.